# How do I specify explicit values on the spot inside a callback function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, callback, xmlhttprequest

This code partly works, but it only moves one progressbar forward when uploading multiple files.  I need to know how I can make it work with multiple XHR objects and multiple progress elements.

```
  var fileinput = document.getElementById('multiple_files_upload');
  var progressbars = document.getElementById('progressbars');
  //for every file...
  for (var x = 0; x < fileinput.files.length; x++) {   

      // CREATING THE PROGRESSBAR           
      var newprg = document.createElement('progress');
      var divIdName = 'prg'+x;
      newprg.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
      newprg.className = "fileprogress";
      newprg.setAttribute('max',100);
      newprg.setAttribute('value',0);          
      progressbars.appendChild(newprg);

      // CREATING THE REQUEST FOR SUBMISSION
      var newfd = new FormData();
      newfd.append('Filedata', fileinput.files[x]);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
          var percentComplete = e.position * 100 / e.totalSize; 
          document.getElementById(divIdName).setAttribute('value',percentComplete);
      }   
    xhr.open('POST', '<?php echo Yii::app()->CreateAbsoluteUrl('album/uploadifyphoto'); ?>', true);
    xhr.send(newfd);  // multipart/form-data

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think everything seems to be right... try to upload a larger file and check the progress... some times, if you upload one/multiple small files... the send method will send large chunk of bytes in a single request (it also depends on your bandwidth)... so the onprogress method calling once... you also need to check the progress on completion of all files upload